# How to fix UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to number failed for value "undefined" at path in Discord.js and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, discord.js

So, I'm trying to set up a simple economy system in Discord.js using MongoDB. I first made a single database for just money. I also set up a command to mock the addition of currency to a user. It worked perfectly fine. Only when I tried to add a second, duplicate system with a different name, schema, and variables etc. did I run into issues. I set up the other database perfectly fine, and it actually worked really well. Then I tried to set up a command to mock adding value to that database, and upon using the command I'm presented with this error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to number failed for value "undefined" at path "stars"`(the second database is called stars). Due to some helpful console logs I implemented I think I tracked the issue to whenever the code hits this:

```
       const starresult = await profileSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
                guildId,
                userId
            }, {
                guildId,
                userId,
                $inc: {
                    stars
                }
            }, {
                upsert: true,
                new: true
            })
```

This code is exactly the same as I used for the first currency except with all the proper variables and stuff like that. Let me know if you need to see any more code. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Here's some code related to stars

The whole related export:

```
const mongo = require('./mongo')
const profileSchema = require('./schemas/profile-schema')

const starsCache = {}

module.exports = (client) => {}

module.exports.addStars = async (guildId, userId, coins, stars) => {
    return await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
        try {
            console.log('Running findOneAndUpdate()')

            const starresult = await profileSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
                guildId,
                userId
            }, {
                guildId,
                userId,
                $inc: {
                    stars
                }
            }, {
                upsert: true,
                new: true
            })

            console.log('RESULT:', starresult)

            starsCache[`${guildId}-${userId}`] = starresult.stars
            
            return starresult.stars
        } finally {
            mongoose.connection.close()
        }
    })
}
```

A section of the profile schema:

```
const profileSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    guildId: reqString,
    userId: reqString,
    stars: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    coins: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },

})
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you what you need to know. You're trying to increment by amount `stars`, but `stars` is undefined. You'll want to look further up in your code to find out why `stars` doesn't have a numeric value.

Comment: The issue is, I think stars does have a numeric value. I'll add some more code to my post.
**EDIT**: The code was added

Comment: You've added in the code in which `stars` is passed in, but not anything that shows when the value of `stars` is set. Have you logged it to the console to confirm that it has a numeric value?

Comment: Update: Not sure what I did but I messed around with some stuff and now it works, thanks!